# Is it possible to change the name of "quick access"?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I've got the CLSID of quick access (679f85cb-0220-4080-b29b-5540cc05aab6) but how would I go about changing the name of it in explorer's navigation pane?

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to rename the quick access toolbar in file explorer at all .

Answer (score 0):

`mklink /j "aaa" "bbb"`
then pin "aaa" to quick access.

Comment: Its unclear how that *actually* renames quick access, as opposed to items in it. Care to elaborate?

Comment: you cannot rename the quick access, but you can name the item which you want to pin to quick access.

Answer (score 0):

Open the below registry location and double click on [LocalizedString].
Change the Data value to your desired name, press enter to confirm. The changes are immediately visible.

```
HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-835353379-3764330216-2755674161-1001\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{679f85cb-0220-4080-b29b-5540cc05aab6}
```

Quick access renamed to Favorites
[image]